# Define the following residue for using the residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I wanna calculate the following integral
$$\oint_{\{\vert z \vert =\frac{5}{2}\}} \frac{1}{sin^2(z)cos(z)}dz$$
with the residuum theorem.
Well first I have to calculate the residue of this integral. We have that $cos(z)=0 \iff \frac{\pi}{2}+k \pi, k \in \Bbb Z$ and $sin(z)=0 \iff z=k \pi, k \in \Bbb Z$. This means, we get the following isolated zero:

- $z_0=0$
- $z_1=\frac{\pi}{2}$
- $z_2=-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Now I have to calculate the residue of the different $z_i$ but for this I have to know, which kind of isolated zero we have. Here is where I got stucked.. How can I find this out?

EDIT: For the real case we have that $sin^2(x)cos(x)=cos(x)-cos^3(x)$. Can I maybe use it here?

Answer (score 1):

To find out which kind of isolated zero you have, you can have a look on the series expansion of $\sin$ and $\cos$ in the point $z_i$. For $z_0=0$ the terms of lowest order of $\sin$ is $z$ and of $\cos$ it is $1$. This means the term of lowest order of $\sin^2(z)\cos(z)$ is $z^2$ and thus you have a second-order pole. Then you can do the same for $z_1$ and $z_2$, where you will find out that you have simple poles.

Another way to do so is you try to find out for which $n$
$$\frac{(z-z_i)^n}{\sin^2(z)\cos(z)}
$$
is holomorphic and nonzero in a neighbourhood of $z_i$, what is actually the [defintion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeros_and_poles) of the order of a pole.

A third way is to calculate the laurent series, which is a very similar method to the first method, but delivers you directly your residue. Again for example for the point $z_0=0$, you have
$$ \sin z=z+\mathcal O(z^3)
$$and
$$ \cos z=1+\mathcal O(z^2)
$$
thus
\begin{align}\frac{1}{\sin^2(z)\cos(z)}&=\frac{1}{(z+\mathcal O(z^3))^2(1+\mathcal O(z^2))}=\frac{1}{z^2(1+\mathcal O(z^2))^2(1+\mathcal O(z^2))}\\
&=\frac{1}{z^2(1+\mathcal O(z^2))(1+\mathcal O(z^2))}=\frac{1}{z^2(1+\mathcal O(z^2))}\\
&=\frac{1}{z^2}(1+\mathcal O(z^2)).
\end{align}
In the last step we have used the geometric series. So your residue in $z_0=0$ is $0$.

Comment: Thank you @mag for your good answer. I like the first two option. I have a question for the first one: "For $_0=0$ the terms of lowest order of $sin$ is $$ and of $cos$ it is $1$. This means you have a second-order pole." I don't see how we can conclude this from this point...

Comment: What I wrote there was a 'descriptive type' of what I did in the third method. As the numerator is $1$ and denominator is $\sin^2z\cos z$ you have to have a look on the terms of lowest order of $\sin^2z\cos z$. Because the term of lowest order will determine the behavior in the neighbourhood of $z_0$, as terms of higher order will tend much faster to $0$. Your case is like $1/f(z)$ with $f(z_0)=0$. If $f$ is like $f(z)=(z-z_0)+\mathcal O((z-z_0)^2)$ the $\mathcal O((z-z_0)^2)$-Term is negligible, as it tends much faster to $0$. To see this exactly you have to do what I did in the trid method.

Comment: I made a small edit to the answer, maybe this helps you a bit to understand it better. The reason why I wrote the first method although it is an imprecise type of the third, is that it is sometimes much easier and faster to do than the third one. And from there you can use the usual method to calculate the residue. For example for the point $z_1$ you know that the term $\sin^2z$ won't disappear in $z_1$ and the term of lowest order thus has to be of order $1$ and for $\cos z$ it has to be of order $(z-z_1)$. So it's very simple whereas the trird method will take a lot of effort.